# Dropzone.js - remove preview file if upload fails

Tags: dropzone.js

I have a problem with my dropzone,

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
Dropzone.options.dropZone = {
    //options here
    maxFilesize: 2,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    removedfile: function(file) {
        var name = file.name;        
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: host+'upload/unfile',
        data: "id="+name,
        dataType: 'html'
        });
        var _ref;
        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;        

        //console.log();
    },
    init: function() {
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
            alert("No more files please!");
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is, when a file fails to upload, it still shows the preview images, so i need that file to be removed automatically when these file fails to upload, how can I do that??

Comment: Tq for smarx, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, if I understand you correctly, you can just delete the image with this code:

```
Dropzone.options.dropZone = {
    ...
    , error: function(file, message, xhr) {
        $(file.previewElement).remove();
    },
    ...
}
```

Just read the documentation again.
This code is from the docs:

```
myDropzone.on("error", function(file) {
  myDropzone.removeFile(file);
});
```

Please let me know, if it works in your case.

Comment: Only the latter worked for me. The first one just removes the preview. then my dropzone, drop-area got shrunk.

Answer (score 0):

When connect error is "xhr.ontimeout", function "error:" don't run.

I need (paste next to "init:"):

```
sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
  //Execute on case of timeout only
  xhr.ontimeout = function(e) {
   alert('connection interrupted');
 };
}
```